# Java exceptions contract of Iterator remove

Tags: java, exception, collections

I'm implementing an [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) which utilises another Iterator, of which I do not know, whether it supports the `remove()` method or not.

Consider the following edge case: the underlying Iterator does *not* support `remove()` and for my Iterator `next()` has not yet been called.

Do I violate the interface contract, if my `remove()` throws – in this situation – an `IllegalStateException` instead of an `UnsupportedOperationException`?
(As soon as `next()` is called, the underlying `remove()` can be called, which will throw the appropriate `UnsupportedOperationException`.)

If so, how could I refactor my code to check whether the underlying Iterator supports `remove()` or not?

---

An example:

```
<T> Iterator<T> getSetViewIterator(Collection<T> collection) {

    Iterator<T> uniqueItr = new HashSet<>(collection).iterator();

    return new Iterator<T>() {
        private T current = null;
        private boolean hasRemoved = true;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return uniqueItr.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            if(!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();

            hasRemoved = false;

            return current = uniqueItr.next();
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            if(hasRemoved)
                throw new IllegalStateException();

            for(Iterator<T> iterator = collection.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                if(iterator.next().equals(current))
                    iterator.remove();
            }

            hasRemoved = true;
        }
    };
}
```

(For our purposes we can assume, that the passed Collection does not contain `null`.)

Comment: Both exceptions are of the kind that should never occur in a well-written application, so I don't see many problems with this in practice.

Comment: Granted, but as a perfectionist it *does* irk me, that `remove()` changes its exception. I believe it should always throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` if the underlying Iterator doesn't support it – I just don't know how to achieve this...

Comment: Well, in that case I'd say you should remember whether you've already thrown an ISE and keep throwing it for the rest of the object's lifetime. I know that isn't what you wanted, but it's consistent.

Comment: That, in turn, would certainly violate the contract, because after a (successful) `next` there is no reason to throw an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: You can throw an `IllegalStateException` at any time, you define your own contract. And once you enter an illegal state, there is no obligation to exit it just because someone called `next()`. The one thing that isn't physically possible is to always throw UOE when the underlying iterator does, even before the first `next()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation you linked to, both exceptions are acceptable for the `remove` method, and the situation of calling `remove` prior to `next` is explicitly mentioned, and allows throwing an `IllegalStateException`.

For an iterator that does not support `remove`, always throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException` is just as valid as throwing the `IllegalStateException` in illegal states (`remove` before `next`, second `remove` after `next`), and only throwing the other exception in valid states (first `remove` after `next`). Both exceptions are applicable to a call in an invalid state - because the state is invalid AND the operation is unsupported.

Your wrapping iterator works just right - it checks the invalid state, and then delegates to an inner iterator, which then may throw its unsupported operation exception. Your iterator does not need to know whether the inner iterator supports remove because, as noted above, in an illegal state both exceptions are valid responses.

Comment: This was also my line of reasoning – I just don't like the asymmetry of the exceptions of `remove`, but I guess I'll have to live with it.